# Create POJOs for every JSON response in different structure?

Tags: java, json

I used RestTemplate to call some 3rd-Party APIs, and RestTemplate will convert received JSON to java POJO automatically like this:

```
Result result = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Result.class);
```

But sometimes the JSON structure is quite simple, such as the two examples:

```
{"access_token":"abcdefg","expires_in":7200}  //only need access_token

{"status":0,"result":{"x":25,"y":46}}  //only need "x" and "y"
```

Should I create POJOs for every JSON response in different structure?

For example, the POJO for the first JSON structure:

```
public class TokenResult {
    private String access_token;
    private String expires_in;

    /* Getters and Setters */
    ......
}
```

For the second JSON structure:

```
public class CoordResult {
    private String status;   
    private Coordinate result;

    /* Getters and Setters */
    ......
}

public class Coordinate {
    private String x;
    private String y;

    /* Getters and Setters */
    ......
}
```

I don't think it is elegant to do so, because some JSON structures are very simple and some are used only once like the "access_token" response.

Any ideas on how to avoid too many simple POJOs?

Comment: If you're looking for elegance, Java rarely is the best language. However, there's no significant downside to having simple classes, and they can evolve later to something more than just simple classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you have there are perfectly fine. Even if it feels you have too many POJOs with property members that are not used this IMO is best and future proof approach. Imagine in near future you need to implement functionality that will require access to `TokenResult.getExpiresIn()` this would mean you would still end up refactoring the base POJO and adding that method and class member.

In similar example with the `CoordResult` I see the `status` as a quite important property that would need checking once the response is received so mapping that to a class member in a POJOs is very good idea.

This will make your code more resilient and also predictive with well defined structure and encapsulating all available data from the response.

Though if you have similar responses in terms of context and structure you can always extend a base POJO and add the relevant class members to a child class.

Another benefit is that this all makes the client code easy to read as we can tell what we expect from the response objects and that can be used in different implementations many of which may not applicable and visible now.

If you decide you don't need all properties of a JSON response you can still use [`@JsonIgnoreProperties`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html) annotation on the class and it'll exclude any unknown elements from the JSON mapping.

EX:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class TokenResult {
    private String access_token;

    // you don't need this
    // private String expires_in;
}
```

Comment: @JsonIgnorePropeties is really useful. And I realized that Generics is a good way to make POJOs more flexible, (e.g.,`CoordResult` can be changed to `BaseResult<CoordResult>`)

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for just some values from the response you could try the org.json package ( http://www.json.org/javadoc/ ).  It has methods to access values in a JSON response.

```
String jsonStr = "{\"access_token\":\"abcdefg\",\"expires_in\":7200}";
String accessToken = new JSONObject(jsonStr).getString("access_token");
```

This approach gets a little more tricky trying to nested values.

Comment: How do you get from `RestTemplate` to what you're proposing?